# Should I back up the data on a RAID 5 that had one drive fail?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, raid, hard-drive-failure

I have a CentOS server that uses a RAID 5 array for data storage.  Recently, one of the four drives in the array failed, and I was wondering whether it makes more sense to back up everything on the drive now or whether it makes more sense to wait for the replacement drive to come and just rebuild the array.

Comment: The only 4 words that matter in this post is “should I back up...” the answer is always yes.

Comment: Thanks.  I was worried that it might cause problems with the existing drives, but then again, if that would cause problems, then rebuilding the array would likely cause the same problems.